# transparently tunnel a keyboard though usb, to another device

Tags: usb, tunnel

I would like to transparently "tunnel" a usb device (keyboard) through Ubuntu so that we have:

```
[usb keyboard] -> [ubuntu box] -> [target box].
```

So, `[target box]` would think it's using `[usb keyboard]` directly.  Is it possible?

I have looked into [usbip](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/), however `[target box]` is an older windows box.  My attempts to get usbip working there have failed.  I am looking now for another solution; a solution that is a **pure usb** solution (via usb cables) would be ideal, but if another alternative exists that uses networking that would be fine too..

Comment: the solution I used that involves networking simply involves the synergy program